# Can you receive more items while items are queued?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I'm idleing in textmode and with other such launch parameters. Apparently, I received items. Items are queued until death, at which time they will be presented to the player. If I don't die, will I still be able to receive new items from the item drop system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you play only in textmode your queued items will still be available to trade. No need to play a normal round and die to get your items. Even if you have done this for, say 4 weeks worth of drops, you'll still be able to trade them.

Go to tf2items.com and put in your steam ID/profile name, etc. and it can tell you what items you have queued. These items are still available to trade whether you are in game or not.

EDIT: You can receive new items while you have items in queue. Your queue can become very large.

Comment: I'm not asking if they will be available to trade, but rather if I will be able to receive new item drops while items are queued (by or not by the item drop system).

Comment: The queue is large enough to hold an entire week's worth of item drops (about 10-11 hours).  Source is personal experience.  You do not need to play a round and die to actually get them in your backpack.  Another way is to click on the "You have new items! View backpack" notification you get on the main menu when you launch TF2 normally.